# Wordpress Shortcode for keywords?

Tags: wordpress, function, shortcode, yoast, wordpress-shortcode

So, I know you can put:

```
function page_title_sc( ){
   return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'page_title_sc' );
```

Into function.php to fetch the page title and get a [page_title] shortcode within Wordpress, but is it possible to do exactly that for keywords?

I put a focus keyword down in Yoast SEO and I would like to have a shortcode for that.

Or another idea: is there a way to have a custom shortcode field in every page? So that I only have to put something into that once and can use it as a shortcode within the whole page?

Comment: Can I ask your use case for this? You say you have a focus keyword in Yoast, are you trying to put this keyword in the content?

Comment: Yeah, basically I want to fetch the keyword of every page, so that I don't have to manually type it up every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a shortcode for Yoast to output the keyphrase automatically:

```
function wpso_61018203_output_yoast_keyphrase() {
    // Make sure Yoast is installed/active.
    if ( class_exists( 'WPSEO_Meta' ) ) :
        // Hold the global post object.    
        global $post;

        return WPSEO_Meta::get_value( 'focuskw', $post->ID );
    endif;
}

add_shortcode('yoast_kw', 'wpso_61018203_output_yoast_keyphrase' );
```

You can then do this `['yoast_kw']` in your content, or use `echo do_shortcode('[yoast_kw]');` in your template.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Do you happen to know whether it's also possible to set a custom word per each page and have that as a shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_post_meta` and grab `_yoast_wpseo_focuskw`:

```
function page_focus_keyword( ){
   return get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw');
}
add_shortcode( 'focus_keyword', 'page_focus_keyword' );
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress filters all content to make sure that no one uses posts and page content to insert malicious code in the database. This means that you can write basic HTML in your posts, but you cannot write PHP code.

And you want to use **Wordpress** `shortcode` for focus keyword.

Possible solution given on Wordpress.org [Yoast SEO plugin support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-yoast-display-focus-keyword/)  query on similar query, and checkout the linked [solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-seo-by-yoast-using-the-focus-keyword-in-php/)

insert the below php snippet in functions.php

```
if(!function_exists('wpseoFocusKW'))
{
        function wpseoFocusKW()
        {
            $focuskw = wpseo_get_value('focuskw', $post->ID);
            echo $focuskw;
        }
}
```

And to use the `shortcode` in another page for **focused keyword**, insert the below shortcode in any pages with `yoast-seo plugin` :

**Shortcode for focus keyword**

```
 [<?php wpseoFocusKW();?>]
```

Comment: That's not a `shortcode`. That's a function. OP wants to use the output within the content. I'm not going to down vote this, but this does not answer the question.